# check MySQL database and add for code PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, html

I have in PHP:

```
<?php

$columns = array('mon','thu','wed','tue', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun');
$num_cols = count($columns);
$col = 0;
$datetime = new DateTime("06:00");

echo "<table>"; // border=\"1\" for visible border

// Day header
echo "<tr>";
foreach($columns as $col) {
    echo "<td at='$col'>$col</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";


// Times
for($i=0; $i<20; $i++) { // FIXME for more entries or other step width
    echo "<tr>";
    $datetime->modify('+30 minutes');

    for ($j=0; $j<$num_cols; $j++)
        echo '<td class="' . $datetime->format('H:i') . '">' . $datetime->format('H:i') . '</td>';

    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

?>
```

and in database MySQL:

```
id | day | hours
1  | mon | 07:00
2  | thu | 08:40
3  | wed | 12:30
4  | thu | 13:00
5  | fri | 05:00
etc
```

how is the best method for checking this? If date is in database then i would like make TD with red background, for example add class red:

```
echo "<td at='$col' class='red'>$col</td>";
```

Check this in each loop FOR is not good idea - this generated to many query for database. 
How can i make it?

I can use also jquery and for example JSON if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List them all in a keyed array, then when looping through the calendar simply check for these keys.

For example, you'd get the array `array(1 => array('07:00' => true))` (day of the week => appointments).

You can then check `isset($array[$datetime->format('N')][$datetime->format('H:i')])`

Comment: could you explain for me this example? i dont understand

Comment: You simply download all information from your database to a local array, instead of querying each time you need something. You then store this in an easily searchable array, by using the keys. `$array[1]` would point at all your appointments on monday, and `$array[1]['08:00']` would be the appointment on monday at 8 AM. This way it only requires one MySQL query.

Comment: thanks :) so how can change my example for use $datetime->format('N') ? now it is impossible...

Comment: the `N` format returns the number of the day of the week. 1 is Monday, 7 is Sunday. You'll want to change this in your database, or simply write a quick function that "maps" them - e.g. mon=1, tue=2, etc

Comment: i know, but in my loop for i dont have access to name day :(